# What happens when I have an array as a property of ApplicationUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have added a property to my ApplicationUser class and made the migration but I don't see any change to my database schema.

If I add data to this array where would it be stored?

Comment: Check if it's stored at all. If so then probably in another table.

Comment: I've looked at every table it's not there. I am able to add a record to it wondering if this is permanently stored or just cached

Comment: Show your context and ApplicationUser classes for starters. Does your context inherit from IdentityDbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not mapped. Actually the only enumerable that *is* mapped is `ICollection`. Anything else will be ignored by EF. As a result, the answer to your question is that it will not be stored. You can have an array property, and you can add stuff to that array, but as soon as the entity is out of scope, it will all be discarded. Nothing will be persisted to your database.

Comment: Which begs the question... how should one best achieve this? Custom additional one-to-many DB table and associated code? Serialised array into json or delimited string stored in an ApplicationUser string field? Maybe it depends on the requirements i.e. expected size of array and whether you need to be able to query the DB based on the contents of the field or simply get/set the entire array as part of the ApplicationUser object.  Presumably if it got large this would also slow down ApplicationUser operations.